# PdfTextExtractor throws NullReferenceException using iText7 in UWP

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

Please, notice that this problem can only be reproduced with **Visual Studio 2017 Preview**. Otherwise, you won't be able to use iText7.

**I'm posting this because it's very likely that the problem will remain when the final version comes out.**

You can reproduce the issue following these steps:

1. Create a new Universal Windows project targeting Windows 10 Insider Preview (build
   16278), also as the minimum version.
2. Add the package iText7, version 7.0.4-netstandard
3. Add one sample PDF file to the root of the project with **Buid Action=Content** and named "doc.pdf". It can be any PDF. I'm using this one: [sample PDF](http://www.educa.jccm.es/es/bolsatra/bolsa-trabajo-secundaria-regimen-especial/eemm-bolsas-sustituciones-curso-escolar-2017-2018.ficheros/210363-Interinos2017_20170905_Candidatos_a_plazas_curso_0590.pdf).
4. Add this code to the MainPage.xaml.cs (code-behind)

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;

namespace App1
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            using (var stream = await GetStream("doc.pdf"))
            {
                var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(stream));
                var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdf.GetPage(1));
            }
        }

        private async Task<Stream> GetStream(string filename)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(new Uri("ms-appx:///"), filename);
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
            return await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

- Run the project

It will throw the NullReferenceException like this:

> at iText.Kernel.Font.DocType1Font.CreateFontProgram(PdfDictionary
>   fontDictionary, FontEncoding fontEncoding, CMapToUnicode toUnicode)
>   at iText.Kernel.Font.PdfType1Font..ctor(PdfDictionary fontDictionary) 
>   at iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(PdfDictionary
>   fontDictionary)    at
>   iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.GetFont(PdfDictionary
>   fontDict)    at
>   iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.SetTextFontOperator.Invoke(PdfCanvasProcessor
>   processor, PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)    at
>   iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral
>   operator, IList`1 operands)    at
>   iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[]
>   contentBytes, PdfResources resources)    at
>   iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfPage
>   page)    at
>   iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage
>   page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy, IDictionary`2
>   additionalContentOperators)    at
>   iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage
>   page)    at App1.MainPage.d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote. This is a genuine problem, and it's well-documented. I looked at the internal communication at iText, and I see that it's been picked up by our QA engineer who made an internal ticket for the development team. This post deserves an up-vote.

Comment: DEVSIX-1599, to be precise. Scheduled to be fixed in 7.0.5.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Hey hi! Is there any estimated date for the release of 7.0.5? :) Thanks!